# I want to own a tavern, but will it hurt my D&D adventure

Tags: dnd-5e, roleplaying, helping

My character really does want to own a tavern after being inspired to do so by a NPC. The original intent of this campaign was to overthrow the "Magic Council" a group of wizards enacting Magic bans over towns, and cities.

Basically they will have magic and no one else will thus tyranny. But my character wouldn't really see it that way, and my DM gets that and is very much so a sandbox DM.

I don't know if I should go for what my character really wants to do, or if I should go adventuring to help my DM. I know my DM could pull me from the tavern for an adventure and all of that but I don't want to make my DM's job harder.

Comment: I don't see a question here, it seems like more of a situation that you are in and want opinions on how to proceed. Opinion-based questions like this that are very specific are generally not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but i see posts like this a lot here?

Comment: What is the specific question here?  Could you succinctly summarize it into a single sentence?

Comment: How many players are in this game?

Comment: I don't think we can give guidance here. Whether or not this will 'hurt' your adventure is going to be entirely dependent on you, your DM, and your table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a "My Guy Syndrome" question.  Our [page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it) for My Guy Syndrome is pretty good and is worth reading.

Briefly: roleplaying is a tool for having fun, and if your roleplaying is causing you to not have fun, you shouldn't do it (or should do it differently).

Also: you're using phrases like "my character wants X" but remember that you are deciding what your character wants, and you can choose to decide differently.

---

If you really want to tell a story where your character buys a tavern, you could tell your DM that your character is buying a tavern and spending a few days taking care of it, and then leaving to go back to adventuring, but he'll come back for it after the adventure is over.

Or, you could tell a story where your character buys a tavern and quits adventuring, so he leaves the group and is now an NPC.  Then you tell the DM that you're bringing in a new character who will take your old character's place in the group.  Most DMs will let you do this at the same experience level and (usually) with the same wealth that your old character had.  If your two characters are friends, you could narrate that your old character gives the new one some of their old equipment since the old one doesn't need it any more.

If neither of these feels correct to you, I recommend you decide that your character wants to do the adventure after all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86694/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-b-i-want-to-own-a-tavern-but-will-it-hurt-my-dd-ad).